# MVC : The view found at '~/.../Index.cshtml' was not created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a modular MVC project to load other special web project within the same runtime.

Other projects are located in a folder at the root of the website called "Modules".
I am using the attribute **PreApplicationStartMethod**  to load the others assemblies inside the sub directories at boot.

I have added special routes to target each modules with the namespace constraints.

I have create a class who implements **RazorViewEngine** to override the *viewPath* when a call is made for the element in the module : ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml -> ~/Modules/ModuleTest/Views/Home/Index.cshtml.

The *Index()* method inside the dynamically loaded library is successfully called but i got an error when the view is rendered :

See following image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/93iJf.png

The framework tell me basically that the view has been found but he will not render it.
Do anyone has any idea why the framework refuse to render it ?

Server Error in '/' Application.

The view found at '~/Modules/ModuleTest/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' was not created.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view found at '~/Modules/ModuleTest/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' was not created.

- Exception

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: The view found at '~/Modules/ModuleTest/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' was not created.]
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +362
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass28.b__19() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408
```

- Controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View(new TestModel() { Value = "Bla" });
        }
    }
```

- View

```
    @using Easily.ModuleTest.Models;
    @{ ViewBag.Title = "Test Index"; }
    @model TestModel
    @Model.Value
```

- CustomRazorViewEngine

```
    public class CustomRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public CustomRazorViewEngine()
        {
            List tmpViewLocationFormats = new List(ViewLocationFormats);
            List tmpMasterLocationFormats = new List(MasterLocationFormats);
            List tmpPartialViewLocationFormats = new List(PartialViewLocationFormats);
            foreach (string moduleDirectory in EasilyModulesContainer.Modules.Select(x => x.Directory))
            {
                foreach (string viewLocationFormat in ViewLocationFormats)
                    tmpViewLocationFormats.Add(viewLocationFormat.Replace("~/", string.Format("~/{0}/{1}/", Constants.ModulesDirectory, moduleDirectory)));
                foreach (string masterLocationFormat in MasterLocationFormats)
                    tmpMasterLocationFormats.Add(masterLocationFormat.Replace("~/", string.Format("~/{0}/{1}/", Constants.ModulesDirectory, moduleDirectory)));
                foreach (string partialViewLocationFormat in PartialViewLocationFormats)
                    tmpPartialViewLocationFormats.Add(partialViewLocationFormat.Replace("~/", string.Format("~/{0}/{1}/", Constants.ModulesDirectory, moduleDirectory)));
            }
            ViewLocationFormats = tmpViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
            MasterLocationFormats = tmpMasterLocationFormats.ToArray();
            PartialViewLocationFormats = tmpPartialViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
        }

        protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
        {
            return base.CreateView(controllerContext, GetPath(controllerContext, viewPath), masterPath);
        }

        protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
        {
            return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, GetPath(controllerContext, partialPath));
        }

        private string GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, string path)
        {
            if (!controllerContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("_module"))
                return path;
            Module module = ModulesContainer.Modules.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("_module"));
            return path.Replace("~/", string.Format("~/{0}/{1}/", Constants.ModulesDirectory, module.Directory));
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your view free of errors?

Comment: What is you compilation mode? Does changing it to compilationMode=”Always" help?

Comment: I have try this but its not changing anything unfortunately

Comment: Could you also add the source code for the Index.cshtml ?

Comment: What do you mean by "create a class who implements RazorViewEngine to override the viewPath"? Did you override CreateView, or what? Can we see your custom razor view engine code also, please?

Comment: @OskarLindberg I have tested with this also, but the same message appear. I guess i miss something to force compilation of the cshtml files outside the View directory but i dont know how to handle that.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes i have check this view is free of any error

Comment: I can't easily reproduce the error. I did notice though that both FindView and FileExists on the RazorViewEngine are called before CreateView. I don't have time to research this further at this time, but I think the error message is correct in that the view was never created. Why? Maybe this will give you some clues: http://blogs.callosmart.com/2010/09/28/compilationmode-problem-in-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1/

Comment: In my experience, the problem with razor always is related to the model that is passed. If the model inherits or extends additional libraries some extra side effects could  be found. The best approach is first, comment the model inclusion and test. The models should be as minimal as possible, without references to libraries in WPF or others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem by debugging into http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/.

I actually load the library who contain the controllers from another folder than bin in my **ModulesContainer** class (see question). But inside **System.Web.Mvc.dll**, one method try to find my controller type by doing a **Assembly.Load()** in the default directory, its why the **BuildManager.GetCompiledType()** return **null**.

I have found a simple way to override this method with :

```cs
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve;
```

and

```cs
private static Assembly CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.RequestingAssembly != null)
            return args.RequestingAssembly;
        Module module = _modules.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Assembly.FullName == args.Name);
        if (module != null)
            return module.Assembly;
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to load assembly {0}", args.Name));
    }
```

I'm just looking inside my *pre-built* dll cache to find the already loaded assembly.

Comment: This looks useful, but where is the _modules variable defined and populated?

Answer (score 0):

@Lex2193: I found problem in your answer.
When I was using your code it was working well except for situation, where referenced assembly has another reference on which it depends:

```
Module [M] => Dependency [D] => DeepDependency [DD]
```

When you use in module object from [D] that has in it some calls to something in [DD]. It will fail on TypeLoad exception. Because of requesting assembly.
So i edited code to first searhing for module:

```
public static Assembly CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly module = modules.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FullName == args.Name);
    if (module != null)
        return module;

    if (args.RequestingAssembly != null)
        return args.RequestingAssembly;

    throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not load file or assembly {0}", args.Name));
}
```